# Relating $\left|\frac{X_2}{X_1}-\frac{EX_2}{EX_1}\right|\leq\frac{2C}{1-C}\left|\frac{EX_2}{EX_1}\right|$ to $|X_i-EX_i|\leq C|EX_i|$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

> If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two random variables and $C <1$  is a constant such that  for each $i=1,2$:
>   $$\operatorname{Prob} \left( \left| X_i-\mathbb{E}X_i \right| \leq C \left| \mathbb{E} X_i\right| \right) \geq 1-\varepsilon_i$$
>   where $0<\varepsilon_i<1$, prove that
>   $$\operatorname{Prob}\left( \left| \frac{X_2}{X_1}-\frac{\mathbb{E}X_2}{\mathbb{E}X_1}\right| \leq \frac{2C}{1-C}\left| \dfrac{\mathbb{E} X_2}{\mathbb{E} X_1}\right| \right) \geq 1-\varepsilon_1-\varepsilon_2$$

I am not clear how the hypotheses imply the quotient of the random variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply the implication, valid for every $C$ in $(0,1)$, $$|x-1|\leqslant C\land|y-1|\leqslant C\implies\left|\frac yx-1\right|\leqslant\frac{2C}{1-C}\tag{1}$$ to $$x=\frac{X_1}{E(X_1)}\qquad y=\frac{X_1}{E(X_1)}$$ to the effect that $A\subseteq A_1\cup A_2$, where $$A_i=\left\{\left| X_i-EX_i \right| > C \left| E X_i\right|\right\}\qquad A=\left\{\left| \frac{X_2}{X_1}-\frac{EX_2}{EX_1}\right| > \frac{2C}{1-C}\left| \frac{EX_2}{EX_1}\right|\right\}$$ hence $$P(A)\leqslant P(A_1)+P(A_2)$$ which implies $$P(A^c)\geqslant1-P(A_1^c)-P(A_2^c)$$ as desired.

---

To show the implication $(1)$, note that, if $$1-C\leqslant x\leqslant1+C\qquad1-C\leqslant y\leqslant1+C$$ then $$\frac{1-C}{1+C}\leqslant\frac yx\leqslant\frac{1+C}{1-C}$$ hence $$-\frac{2C}{1+C}\leqslant\frac yx-1\leqslant\frac{2C}{1-C}$$ Since $$\frac{2C}{1+C}\leqslant\frac{2C}{1-C}$$ this shows that $$-\frac{2C}{1-C}\leqslant\frac yx-1\leqslant\frac{2C}{1-C}$$ and the proof is complete.